# How to delete duplicate elements between two javascript arrays?

Tags: javascript, arrays

```js
a = [
  { id: 1, books: [1, 2, 3, 4] },
  { id: 2, books: [1, 2, 3] },
  { id: 3, books: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] },
  { id: 9, books: [1, 2] }
];

b = [{ id: 2, books: [1, 2, 3] }, { id: 3, books: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] }];
```

I want to delete array `b` the same `id` elements from `a`.
How to do that? Thanks.

It means:

I want to get the `a = [{id: 1, books: [1,2,3,4]}]`, get rid the same element within array `b`;

my code is:

```js
const delDuplicate = (a, b) => {
  const bLen = b.length;
  if (!bLen) return a;
  for (let i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < bLen; j++) {
      if (a[i].id === b[j].id) {
        const delItem = a.splice(i, 1)[0];
        console.log(delItem);
      }
    }
  }
  return a;
};

a = delDuplicate(a, b);
```

It works, is there a better way? I think `reduce` and `map` maybe work too.

These two arrays are not simple array. So can not use `a.indexOf(b[i]) !== -1`.

Comment: Did you try anything yourself?

Comment: Could you clarify a little: you want to delete elements that match in both arrays (same position and value) from the second array? Or is it that you want to delete elements that have the same id regardless of value/pos from the second array?

Comment: @AshwinGupta I edited the question, sorry, my English is not good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `.map()`, `.reduce()`, `.filter()`, `.indexOf()`

```
var ids = b.map(o => o.id);
a = a.reduce((res, o) => 
      [...res] = [...res.filter(Boolean), ids.indexOf(o.id) < 0 && o], []);
```

```js
var a = [{id: 1, books: [1,2,3,4]}, {id: 2, books: [1,2,3]}, {id: 3, books: [1,2,3,4,5]}, {id: 9, books: [1,2]}];
var b = [{id: 2, books: [1,2,3]}, {id: 3, books: [1,2,3,4,5]}];

var ids = b.map(o => o.id);
    a = a.reduce((res, o) => 
      [...res] = [...res.filter(Boolean), ids.indexOf(o.id) < 0 && o], []);

console.log(a);
```

Answer (score 2):

I found another way to do this. By looping through both arrays and if a match/duplicate is NOT found add this element to a third array. The third array can over write the A array at the end if required. Have tested and works.

```
var a = [{id: 1, books: [1,2,3,4]}, {id: 2, books: [1,2,3]}, {id: 3, books: [1,2,3,4,5]}, {id: 9, books: [1,2]}];
var b = [{id: 2, books: [1,2,3]}, {id: 3, books: [1,2,3,4,5]}];
var c = []; // New array to sort parsed A array
var boolMatch; // Boolean if duplicate is found

for(i = 0; i < a.length; i++){
    boolMatch = false; // Required to reset the Boolean at the start of each loop
    for(j = 0; j < b.length; j++){
        if(a[i].id == b[j].id){
            boolMatch = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if(!boolMatch) c.push(a[i]); // Add to C array if element from A is NOT found in B array
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly: your question is a bit unclear to me. If you clarify, I can make this answer better. I'm asuming that you are trying to remove elements from b that have same value as the corresponding element in array a. I'm also assuming that you want to update the incidences during the search.

Now IDK the exact syntax of Javascript, so this may be a bit off. However, it should give you a general  idea of what to do. (I'll try and fix the code after I research a bit)

```
a = [{id: 1, books: [1,2,3,4]}, {id: 2, books: [1,2,3]}, {id: 3, books: [1,2,3,4,5]}, {id: 9, books: [1,2]}]
b = [{id: 2, books: [1,2,3]}, {id: 3, books: [1,2,3,4,5]}]

//set loop size to size of the smaller array
var lsize=b.length;
if(a.length<b.length) lsize = a.length;

//loop through length 
for(var i = 0; i < lsize; i++) {
    if(a[i] != b[i]) { //check if the values of the elements are the same
       b.splice(i, 1); //remove the element from b
       i=-1; //reset loop to check rest of elements
       lsize-=1; //reduce size since there is one less
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To make sure you compare all the elements correctly, you should sort them by the `id`s to make sure you're comparing the right array elements together.  This solution assumes the objects only have one other property to compare, `books`, which is a sorted array.

```
// initialize arrays
var a = [{id: 1, books: [1,2,3,4]}, {id: 2, books: [1,2,3]}, {id: 3, books: [1,2,3,4,5]}, {id: 9, books: [1,2]}];
var b = [{id: 2, books: [1,2,3]}, {id: 3, books: [1,2,3,4,5]}];
// comparator
var comp = function(a,b) {
    return a.id-b.id;
};
// index for array a
var j = 0;
// sort arrays
a.sort(comp);
b.sort(comp);

// check all elements in b against those with matching ids in a
for(var i=0; i<b.length; i++) {
    // find next matching id in a
    while(a[j].id<b[i]&&j<a.length) {
        j++;
    }
    // break if no more elements to check against in a
    if(j==a.length) {
        break;
    }

    // compare elements with matching ids to see if the books array make the same string
    // comparing array references won't work, so they're converted to strings instead
    if(a[j].id==b[i].id&&a[j].books.join(",")==b[i].books.join(",")) {
        // remove element from b and don't skip over next element
        b.splice(i,1);
        i--;
    }
}
// b should share no elements with a
```