# How can I use underscore's _.uniq function to help log even and odd numbers?

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, underscore.js, unique

I'm pretty new to JavaScript, but this is what I have so far. I am trying to use underscore to help print this to the console in two batches of unique even and odd numbers, I think I am like 90% of the way there but I hit a wall.

```
var arr = ([1,3,5,2,0,4,5,2,9,9,8,2]);            
sort(arr);

function sort(arr) {

var evens = [];
var odds = [];                        
for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {            
    if(arr[i] % 2 ){            
        odds.push(arr[i]);            
    } else if(!(arr[i] % 2)) {            
        evens.push(arr[i]);            
}            
}            

console.log("ODD NUMBERS:" + " " + odds);            
console.log("EVEN NUMBERS:" + " " + evens);            
if(_.uniq(evens).length != evens.length || _.uniq(odds).length != odds.length){            
console.log("FAIL!");            
}             
}
```

Comment: What exactly is the wall you're hitting? You should be seeing "FAIL!" each time because your input array has duplicates (both even and odd), so the `uniq` lengths will never be the same as the sorted lengths. What are you seeing and what are you expecting to see?

Comment: Hi Scott - I'm getting both lists printed out to the console with all even or odd numbers included in the log in addition to an error (using CodePad) that tells me ReferenceError: _ is not defined. I'm expecting no errors and and both lists printed to the console with unique values.

Comment: That error means Underscore is not loaded. I haven't used CodePad in a while, but I'm sure there's a way to include libraries. In JSFiddle it's on the left-hand side. Once you find it, you'll want to add a url for Underscore, like this one: https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.3/underscore.js

Comment: Also, you're printing the arrays before calling the `_.uniq` method. You need to wrap the `odds` and `evens` in `_.uniq()` to get the unique arrays from the full arrays.

Comment: Thank you! You've been super helpful but one more thing - as I said I'm super new, I'm not quite sure what you mean by wrapping the even and odds in uniq. Would you be willing to provide me with one example?

Comment: Sure thing. See my answer posted below.

Comment: Underscore provides the nifty [partition](http://underscorejs.org/#partition) function which together with es6 destructuring would simplify the filtering: `let [evens, odds] = _.partition(arr, number => number % 2 == 0);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you need to filter your array (even or odd) and then apply _.uniq

```js
var arr = [1,3,5,2,0,4,5,2,9,9,8,2];

var evens = _.filter(arr, function(num){ return num % 2 == 0; });
var odds = _.filter(arr, function(num){ return num % 2 != 0; });

console.log("EVEN NUMBERS: "+_.uniq(evens));
console.log("ODD NUMBERS: "+_.uniq(odds));
```

```html
<script src="http://underscorejs.org/underscore-min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

`arr[i] % 2` evaluates to `0`, or `false` at `if` condition

```
if (arr[i] % 2 === 0) { 
  // even
} else {
  // not even
}
```

Comment: I've fixed this - however it still prints out a list of all evens or odds, not unique values.

Comment: Have not tried `underscore.js`. You can remove duplicates from an array without using a library. [How to delete duplicate elements between two javascript arrays?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38865131/how-to-delete-duplicate-elements-between-two-javascript-arrays/)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I got your requirements right, but here's how you can do it with ES6.

[`filter` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) is widely supported in most of the browsers and allows to dissect arrays in a more declarative way.

```js
const arr = [1,3,5,2,0,4,5,2,9,9,8,2]; 
const isEven = el => el % 2 === 0;
const isOdd = el => el % 2 !== 0;
const evens = arr.filter(isEven);
const odds = arr.filter(isOdd);
console.log(`Unique evens: ${_.uniq(evens)}`); // => "Unique evens: 2,0,4,8"
console.log(`Unique odds: ${_.uniq(odds)}`); // "Unique odds: 1,3,5,9"
```

Answer (score 0):

**First problem: `ReferenceError: _ is not defined.`**
Be sure that a `<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.3/underscore.js"></script>` is somewhere in your html file or that Underscore has been required in your JS file another way.

**Second problem: "I'm expecting no errors and both lists printed to the console with unique values."**
This isn't happening because you haven't yet called the `uniq` function on the arrays. Just wrap the two arrays with `_.uniq()`, like so:

```
console.log("ODD NUMBERS:", _.uniq(odds));
console.log("EVEN NUMBERS:", _.uniq(evens));
```

Alternately, you could call `_.uniq` on the input array before sorting it, thus saving you processing time as you sort.

Either way, assuming Underscore is defined, you should get your expected result.